# multiple docroot depent on first domain name

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Atm we have some rewrite rules which look for resurces based on the first domain name.
We would like to improve it, so we don't have to copy the base template files out to each folder ond then the specific files to the specific folders.

the rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^web([0-9]{1})\.localhost(.*)$ C:/dir/http/test/htdocs/$1$2 [L]
```

we are looking for a way to improve it. If the above gives a 404 then we would like to look at another location like: C:/dir/http/test/htdocs/base/$2
If this gives a 404 then it's ok.

I have tried to put RewriteCond in front without any luck.

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewiteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewiteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/web([0-9]{1})\.localhost(.*)$
RewriteCond C:/dir/http/test/htdocs/%1%2 -f
RewriteRule ^ C:/dir/http/test/htdocs/%1%2 [L]

RewiteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewiteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/web([0-9]{1})\.localhost(.*)$
RewriteCond C:/dir/http/test/htdocs/base/%2 -f
RewriteRule ^web([0-9]{1})\.localhost(.*)$ C:/dir/http/test/htdocs/base/$2 [L]
```